# Jsoup's getelementbyid not working in asynctask

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm using getElementById method of jsoup to get the content of id "content-main".When i'm running it as a java application everything works as it should, but as an android app not.I just get null.I'm using the following code inside doInBackground of AsyncTask.

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.blabla.com").get();
Element t=doc.body().getElementById("content-main");
System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: Does your android have access to the internet?

Comment: Great :-). But please make a post and accept this answer. (see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ ). So everyone can see this topic is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does although i 've found where the problem was.I was loading the moble version of my site where this id did'n exist.Thanks anyways